# Categories with main categories (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to do the following :

I have `categories` model that **has_many** `posts` model.

On my `categories`, I use `action_text` for body text content.

**My issue:** I would like to create a main page that lists all `categories` and their `posts` on a view. And jus like a regular category, I want that page to have an `action_text` field for me to populate it with body text content (saved in database of course).

Then I want my routes to be as such :

```
match '/all' => 'pages#all_content', :via => :get,   :as => :all_content
match '/:category_id' => 'pages#category', :via => :get,   :as => :category
match '/:category_id/:post_id' => 'pages#post', :via => :get, :as => :post
```

My unsure solution : Add a boolean `main` field to my `category` model. That allows me to be able to populate it with content just like a regular category. And then, on my `pages#all_content`, I can request the main category to have all its data.

But I'm very insecure about this solution because I think there must be a better/cleaner one. Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't mix those things. Using main to get one category just for the ActionText Content sounds more like a Hack. Sounds like you like to make some kind of mini-CMS?

I would rather :

- a) create a new model, Pages (also with Action Text if you need).  Maybe give each page a unique "key", which identifies where to load that Page model (e.g. `Page.find_by(key: "categories_top")`) -> If you later have different parts of the page which you need to CMSify, that approach is the relatively future-proof
- b) But if the text does not change very often, I would just put the HTML into the view directly,
- c) or into a separate Markdown file, if it is a lot of copy and you would rather not write HTML directly, and load that (using redcarpet Gem for instances)

Comment: Exactly it's a CMS with a back office.

Solution a) sounds like a good one. Thank you very much.